# Display only posts with comments

Tags: posts, comments, shortcode

I have this code to show recent posts from one category. I need to show only the posts which have comments. How can i do that via shortcode?

```
/* Shortcode to output recent posts from one category */

function display_cat_recent_posts() {
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page'=> 5,
'cat'=> 10,
);
$cat_recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $cat_recent_posts->have_posts() ):
$output = '<ul>';
while ( $cat_recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $cat_recent_posts->the_post();
$output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
endwhile;
$output .= '</ul>';
endif;
return $output;
wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode( 'recent-posts', 'display_cat_recent_posts' );
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a loop you can use the function [`get_comments_number()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number).

> Retrieves the value of the total number of comments, Trackbacks, and Pingbacks for a post. This tag must be within The Loop. Unlike [`comments_number()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number) this function will return the value as a numeric value.

Use it for example as follows:

```
$num_comments = get_comments_number();

if ( $num_comments > 0 )
    $output .= "...";
```

So your code could look like this:

```
/* Shortcode to output recent posts from one category */
function display_cat_recent_posts() {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'=> 5,
    'cat'=> 10,
  );

  $cat_recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( $cat_recent_posts->have_posts() ):
    $output = '<ul>';
    while ( $cat_recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $cat_recent_posts->the_post();
      if ( get_comments_number( ) > 0 ):
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
      endif;
    endwhile;

    $output .= '</ul>';
  endif;

  return $output;

  wp_reset_postdata();
}

add_shortcode( 'recent-posts', 'display_cat_recent_posts' );
```

Comment: how can i use this with the function (shortcode) above?

Comment: I improved my answer for you

Comment: I put this code in function.php but didn't work...

Comment: Thats useful information. What didn't work? Did you get a kind of error (if so, what did the error show), what have you tried to make it work? "didn't work" isn't enough to work with.

Comment: When i use it without if ( get_comments_number( ) > 0 ): i get 5 post from the category. When i use it with if ( get_comments_number( ) > 0 ): i get nothing for output...